# Moving a column in a row using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have divide the web page into **3 columns** as follows. And filled the `div` with a image in `javascript`.

```
<div id="fullPage" class="image-motion-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" align="left" id="left">   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" align="center" id="center">   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" align="right" id="right">     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to move first **column(with it's image)** left to right using `Javascript`.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Comment: does this happen just once? are you trying to make this happen on a timer? does it move just one column? does it animate or snap?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".row div:first-child").className += "col-md-offset-8"` or `document.getElementById("left").className += "col-md-offset-8"`

Comment: How was the image added?

Comment: @Banzay: Yes, I'm using bootstrap

Comment: @haxxxton: I need to happen it once and just animate.

Comment: @Nim That means, you just need to slide the div left to right ?

Comment: @Nim Are you looking for something like this? http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/EmqCx

Comment: @Tushar, I think she need to move the first coloumn move freely here and there in the page. Since there are other two div s (center and right) are blocking, she couldn't do.

Comment: @LakmalVithanage: yes,that's what I looking for

Answer (score 2):

You should try this yourself. 
I created a fiddle for you. A very simple one. Give it a try it'll be helpful to understand the concept.

```
  $("#left").insertAfter($("#right"));
```

[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/m6djm/123/)

```
$("#left").insertAfter($("#right"));
$("#center").insertAfter($("#right"));
```

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/m6djm/124/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't want to do this, but one option would be to use flex and order to do that.

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.row div {
    order: attr(data-order);
}
```

JS

```
function changeOrder() {
    document.getElementById('left').setAttribute('data-order', '4');
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="fullPage" class="image-motion-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" data-order="1" id="left">   
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" data-order="1" id="center">   
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" data-order="2" id="right">     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This doesn't work with some older browsers, but I like how easy it is to manipulate, given that you only have to change `data-order` and the rest of it takes care of itself. I'm not sure if you wanted to do this with a timer, buttons, etc., but regardless of what it is, you just need to make sure the element you want on the left's `data-order` is less than the center's, which is less than the one you want on the right's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (jQuery required):

```
var $cols = $('#fullPage .row:first-child > div').clone();
var $row = $('#fullPage .row:first-child').empty();

$row.append($cols[1]); // Put 2nd column first
$row.append($cols[0]); // Put 1st column next
$row.append($cols[2]); // Last column stays in the same place
```